# WPF Element Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have two controls within my `UserControl` where I bind to the exact same object using Element Binding:

```
AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}"
```

On the first control it works fine but on the second I get a binding exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MainGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CanContinue; DataItem=null; target element is 'WizardPage' (Name='DeductionPage'); target property is 'AllowNext' (type 'Boolean')
```

I have also tried using `RelativeSource` binding on the second control:

```
AllowNext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}"
```

But this also gives me an error.

Does anyone know what this might be?

--

Here is the simplified control:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <w:Wizard Name="MyWizard" w:Designer.PageIndex="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.Policy}" >
        <w:WizardPage Header="Main Member" MaxHeight="600" AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}" Name="MainPage">
        </w:WizardPage>
        <w:WizardPage Name="DeductionPage" Header="Policy Details" AllowBack="False" AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}">
        </w:WizardPage>
    </w:Wizard>
</Grid>
```

Now as I mentioned, MainPage binds fine, whereas the DeductionPage does not bind at all and gets the supplied error. The DataContext of MainGrid is set from code behind:

```
    public void SetDataContext(object o)
{
  MainGrid.DataContext = o;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the source for your UserControl? My first guess is that this may be a DataContext issue?

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's the MainGrid which is the binding source is not in the logical tree of your binding target.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem absolutely with the binding element. However, you didn't give the source so You want to debug it and solve the issue.

Refer the below url and "`Cannot find source for binding with reference`" section where explained obviously how to debug and solve it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244107/Debugging-WPF-data-bindings

Comment: Thanks I did have a look at this before posting here. This did not help me find the solution. When "Using trace messages" all of my properties etc are spelled correctly as they are copied from the page which works, also the converter does not work in this case and the author admits that it is limited!

Comment: <Grid Name="MainGrid">
   <w:Wizard Name="MyWizard" w:Designer.PageIndex="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.Policy}" >
        <w:WizardPage Name="DeductionPage" Header="Policy Details" AllowBack="False" AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}">
        </w:WizardPage>
    </w:Wizard>
</Grid>

Comment: If you have the controls like above what happens? I just removed the 1st control only i've a second one.

Comment: Okay, so when removing the first page and leaving the second it all works perfectly on the second page. I have no idea what this might be. I'm using the `AvalonWizard`.

Comment: I'm not much aware about AvalonWizard. However, I advice you to try the different path in the second control from the MainGrid. then we will conclude what was the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: <Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <w:Wizard Name="MyWizard" w:Designer.PageIndex="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.Policy}" >
        <w:WizardPage Header="Main Member" MaxHeight="600" AllowNext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.CanContinue}" Name="MainPage">
        </w:WizardPage>
        <w:WizardPage Name="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=Name}" Header="Policy Details" AllowBack="False">
        </w:WizardPage>
    </w:Wizard>
</Grid>

Comment: see in the above example, i removed AllowNext and binding the name from the parent. I try to validate Is this the problem only with the data context path or else everypath  ?

Comment: The problem remains even when binding to `Name`, so it isn't just with `DataContext`

Comment: Absolutely, Otherwise try the datacontext in the Window level and try to work on it.

Comment: I have changed around how my binding works a bit and realized that the second page cannot pick up the `MainGrid` at all, I'm assuming the problem lies with `AvalonWizard` and have asked this question in their forum! Thanx for the help.

Comment: Yes. I'm also thinking the same. You can get the answer over there. Once you get the answer dont forget to publish here. It's helpful for someone else who is looking into the same issue.

Comment: Hi Again, I'm having the same problem again even though I am not using the `AvalonWizard`, if I update my code would you mind having a look?